# First post full width, rest in two columns

Tags: columns

Here is my loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

<?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
    <?php if ($i++ == 0) : ?>

        <div class="entry-content-main">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div class="entry-content-rest">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and my css

```
.entry-content-rest {
    width: 48.5%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 7px;
    }
```

This displays my content as follow

```
Post1

Post2      Post3

Post4      Post5
```

My problem is, say post 2 is longer (have more contents) than post 3, then my columns is displayed way wacky like this

```
Post1

Post2      Post3

open       Post4

Post5      Post6
```

Any suggestions to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could rewrite the full code and use the build-in loop counter `$wp_query->current_post` to fix the css classses and add a class for the first post per row to clear the float to prevent the 'wacky sticking';

example:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

        <div class="entry-content-<?php echo (( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) ? 'main' : 'rest' ); if( $wp_query->current_post%2 == 1 ) echo ' left-post'; ?>">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

additional css:

```
.left-post { clear: left; }
```

Comment: michael, how do i use your code in category.php of twenty twelve child theme. I know i need to put echo '<div>' loop without the php tags echo '</div>', but when i do it, i get the following error: Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' in C:\Documents and Settings\Pieter\Desktop\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\pietergoosen\category.php on line 33

Comment: this is rather a question of when and how to switch from php tags to html tags; here is the corresponding code section: http://pastebin.com/ZMyZA0CQ

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do all that work on the PHP side as CSS can handle this using [nth selectors](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/). Also, because all these children are prefixed you might as well use [attribute selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).

[WORKING DEMO - JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kf95j9o1/embedded/result/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: snow;
    color: dimgrey;
}

.items {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

.items [class^="entry-content-"] .copy {
    padding: 15px;
}

.items [class^="entry-content-"] {
    background: gainsboro;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    width: 48.5%;
    float: left;
}

.items [class^="entry-content-"]:first-of-type {
    background: skyblue;
    color: snow;

    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.items [class^="entry-content-"]:nth-child(even) {
    clear: both;
}

.items [class^="entry-content-"]:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

---

### DEMO CONTENT

Using jQuery we can produce random content to check various sizes and how they affect the layout. In these cases; first item is full width, left items float left, right items float right and the next row follows the largest item. See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kf95j9o1/embedded/result/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="entry-content-main">Main</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 1</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 2</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 3</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 4</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 5</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 6</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="items">
    <div class="entry-content-main">Main</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 1</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 2</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 3</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 4</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 5</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 6</div>
    <div class="entry-content-rest">Post 7</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function range(min, max){
    var range = max-min;
    return Math.floor( Math.random()*range ) + min;
}

// words to use
var things = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi feugiat.").split(' ');

// random word factory
function getWords(count){ 
  var stuff = [];
    while(count && count>0){
     var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];  
     stuff.push(thing);
     count--;
  }
  return stuff.join(' ');
}

var $ = $ || jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {

   // add random content to all entries
   $('.items [class^="entry-content-"]').each(function(inx, item){
        var $item = $(item),
        words = getWords ( range ( 5, 200) );
        $item.html ( '<div class="copy">POST ' + inx + " - " + words + '</div>' );
   });

   // add random header content
   $('.items [class^="entry-content-"]:first-of-type').each(function(inx, item){
        var $item = $(item),
        words = getWords ( range ( 5, 20) );
        $item.html ( '<h1 class="copy">MAIN ' + inx + " - " + words + '</h1>');
   });
});
```

Colors via [neilorangepeel](http://colours.neilorangepeel.com)

Comment: Digging deep into archives here :-). Wonder 2 and half years later how many people are still stuck with browsers that does not support CSS3. Strange how many people in SA are still stuck with IE8 (*no wonder because Windows 7 was still shipped with IE8 IIRC*) which does not support CSS3. I tend to avoid client side solutions (*if I'm looking for relibility*) as browsers differ and client side can be manipulated like JS. Anyways, thanks for the input

Comment: Great news! EOL for IE < 11 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support + http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 >= IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what I have figured out.

For displaying First post with full width and rest in two columns.

```
<?php $i=0; $j=0;?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if ($i==0){ 
      echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">'; //<-- bootstrap

      //you can also call get_the_title and the_content function if you are
      //doing theme customization instead of using get_template_part


      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
      echo '</div>';
         }
if($j<=1){
      echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">';
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
      echo '</div>';
        }
        $i ++;
        $j ++;

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
```

[image]
If you want to display First post with full width and rest in three columns you
can simply do this just by

```
 <?php $i=0; ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 <?php
        // Start the loop.
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  if ($i==0){   
     echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">';
     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
     echo '</div>';
     }
        else{
      echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">';
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
      echo '</div>';
        }
        $i ++;

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
```

The result will be
[image]