# List of authors posts minus very latest

Tags: posts, loop, author

I'm creating an **authors.php** page to display all the posts for the author clicked.

But the list(s) needs to show the very **first** / **latest** post so I can style it diferently than the rest of the posts?

I did think of just having 2 queries, one query just displaying the very first post, so I can style the thumbnail size, title size etc. in this loop;

```
<! -- Start the Loop . -->
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
           title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
    <?php the_excerpt();
endwhile;
endif;
```

Then another query minus the first post?

I'd like it done in a way so I can easily style it using divs etc. Does that make sense and is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First post full width, rest in two columns](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98915/first-post-full-width-rest-in-two-columns)

Comment: You can also use CSS3 Selectors to style nth children differently http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 -- in your case, `:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for multiple queries - posts are, by default, ordered by most recent. Just apply a classname for the first post on the first page:

```
<article <?php post_class( $wp_query->current_post === 0 && ! is_paged() ? 'my-awesome-first-post' : '' ) ?>
```

The first post of the first page will have the class `my-awesome-first-post`.

**Update:** Based on your updated question's code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

    <div <?php post_class( $wp_query->current_post === 0 && ! is_paged() ? 'first-post' : '' ) ?>>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Ahh OK so how could I fit this within a query; thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Just put it in your loop in `authors.php`

Comment: Tried adding that to my query but no luck; would it be possible to wrap the first post in a div titled first-post?

Comment: See my revised answer.